# A problem with regex (non wanted end)

Tags: php, regex

I have the following pattern:

```
(name|id)\s*=\s*('|")([a-zA-Z\-\_])+('|")
```

And I have to get all attributes **name="a"** or **id="ab_c"** which does not have the structure **name="a-element"** or **id="a-element"** (finishes with **-element**), I tried with:

```
(name|id)\s*=\s*('|")([a-zA-Z\_][^-element])+('|")
```

but it does not work, what is the mistake??

Comment: Is this string part of some XML or HTML?  If so, don't parse it with a regex (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  Instead, use `DOMElement` (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) (or another XML parser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [negative look-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word/406408#406408), like this:

```
(name|id)\s*=\s*('|")([a-zA-Z\-_](?!-element))+('|")
```

(But keep in mind that you probably shouldn't be parsing XML manually.)